# Are there any alternitives to the WCFTestClient

Tags: wcf

Are there any open source (or not) alternatives to the WCFTestClient?

The WCFTestClient has a lot of limitations that make it hard to work with (for example it does not support Entity Framework objects).

So I am looking to see if there is anything else out there that may be better (or even different).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[WCF Storm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/default.aspx) or the open-source [Storm](http://www.codeplex.com/storm)

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to create actual unit tests to test servers I write. The idea is that they can be rerun frequently.

You can also try [soapUI](http://soapUI.org).

Comment: Whilst an excellent philosophy, that doesn't necessarily cover all the use cases for a generic test client (not least tracking down issues with edge cases in live services - ideally, to agree with you in part, prior to writing tests demonstrate the issue and its subsequent removal!)