# How do I test my WCF duplex service?

Tags: wcf

I am currently developing a duplex WCF service and I wish to test the service using the WcfTestClient.exe that is provided by Visual Studio 2010. However as my WCF service is a duplex, the ending point are created as shown:

```
selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPostingService), new WSDualHttpBinding(), "Posting");
```

apparently after running wcftestclient.exe and connecting to the service, it says that it is not supported for dual http bindings.

Any idea how else can I test my WCF service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880185/are-there-any-alternitives-to-the-wcftestclient) which offers some alternatives to wcfclient.

I would just write a simple console application to test it, but that would require you to configure the bindings outside the wcfclient. You can use WCF Configuration Editor (from Tools menu) to assist with binding configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Host the WCF application, Once it is started do the following..
Use 'Poster' a add on in Mozilla.
Set appropriate return type, pass the url to your WCF application.
Set Post method and you are done.